# Using Keyboard Over UART In C.H.I.P

Tags: linux, serial

I have recently bought a C.H.I.P. and because it only has 1 USB port, I thought it would be nice if a USB Keyboard could be interfaced to C.H.I.P. through its UART port, with a USB - RS232 adapter. However I don't have much Linux knowledge, I am a fresh EE graduate. Can this be done, if so with which tools?

Comment: Why not use a USB hub to plug in mouse/keyboard and other useful stuff?

Comment: It will probably be useful to you beyond this project and save you a whole lot of effort getting the UART interface to work. (Don't forget, the USB-RS232 dongle will require power which may be difficult to supply from the C.H.I.P) I do think what you want is doable, once you have the interface electronics worked out turn on an 'agetty' process in /etc/inittab and you should be able to login over RS-232 port.

Comment: I have read several posts that only a powered USB hub works on C.H.I.P. I also thought it would be a reason for me to finally get in the Linux world. :) Thank you for answering.